# TypeScript understands conditional type at call site but not usage site?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a function that will extract a string or number from a passed-in object. The caller is allowed to either 1) pass in a function that takes the object and returns `string | number` or 2) pass in the name of a property that is a string or number.

Conditional types in 2.8 seem like they should be able to do this (and they sort of do!) but unfortunately getting TS not to complain when I use the property name requires a type assertion through `any` which seems incorrect. At the call site of the function the type *is* checked properly, so I don't think I'm miles away from the right answer.

```
type RowKey = string | number;
type RowKeyableNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends RowKey ? K : never }[keyof T];
type RowKeyable<T> = Pick<T, RowKeyableNames<T>>;
type RowKeySel<T> = { (val: T): RowKey; } | RowKeyableNames<T>;
const getRowKey = <T extends {}>(val: T, sel: RowKeySel<T>): RowKey => {
    if (typeof sel === 'function') {
        return sel(val);
    } else {
        // This shouldn't error, but it does! See error message below.
        return val[sel];
    }
}

interface Foo {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    contents: any[];
}

function myThing(foo: Foo): RowKey {
    // works, like it should.
    getRowKey(foo, 'id');
    getRowKey(foo, 'name');

    // errors, like it should! That's what we want.
    getRowKey(foo, 'contents');
}
```

The error message I get back is:

```
Type 'RowKey[] | T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends RowKey ? K : never; }[keyof T]][]' is not assignable to type 'RowKey[]'.
  Type 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends RowKey ? K : never; }[keyof T]][]' is not assignable to type 'RowKey[]'.
    Type 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends RowKey ? K : never; }[keyof T]]' is not assignable to type 'RowKey'.
      Type 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends RowKey ? K : never; }[keyof T]]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

I'm hoping to avoid the double-type-assertion (`as any as RowKey`), but I may have to go that route.

**The question is: What do I need the type of `RowKeySel<T>` to look like for this to work without the double type-assertion?**

*Edit:* My best guess is that the other keys of `T` aren't really removed by this conditional type, they're just set to `never`. Therefore, `val[sel]` is maybe (??) being interpreted as `string | number | never`?

Comment: Not likely related but there is a difference between function types and method types

Comment: This is probably a limitation of the ability of the compiler to analyze conditional types depending on generic type parameters.  You understand that `T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string | number ? K : never; }[keyof T]]` must be a subtype of `string | number`, but the compiler doesn't.  I think the assertion (through `any` I guess) might be the best thing to do for now.  Not sure.

Comment: Note also that `string | number | never` is reduced to `string | number` by the compiler, so that isn't your problem.